# WPF Property value is different from binded value

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a checkbox whose IsEnabled property is bind to a read-only property of its data context. But the result is not as expected always. Actually, that property is being computed in a Task (threading) in view model's constructor

I was under the impression that computed value is somehow different but upon inspecting on snoop, it shows IsEnabled property of checkbox to False and in data context tab that property is True.

I believe this is due to threading and whenever view loads prior to completing that thread execution, it displays wrong value.

Previously I used this for binding

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsFeatureAvailable}"
```

Later in hope of fixing this, I use this

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsFeatureAvailable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

but there is no change, any suggestions

I am using Framework version 4.5.2 and Caliburn micro for MVVM

Comment: Are you implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? How do you set the source property?

Comment: If you are using MultiThreading then consider using the `Dispatcher` and trigger the notification on the UI thread. I had this problem with notifications not showing just because I didn't call `OnPropertyChanged` through Dispatcher.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `IsFeatureAvailable` property whenever it's set to a new value:

```
public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private _isFeatureAvailable;
        public bool IsFeatureAvailable
    {
        get { return _isFeatureAvailable; }
        set
        {
            _isFeatureAvailable = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsFeatureAvailable);
        }
    }
}
```